# Separate button for MapTypeId.TERRAIN using google maps api 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

My current understanding is that the google maps api3 MapTypeId.TERRAIN shows up as a checkbox option, when the user hovers over the MAP button (MapTypeId.ROADMAP). I'd like to break this out into a separate button, having 3 buttons one for each mapTypeId (ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN). 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Implement a [Custom Control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls). When it's clicked, set the mapTypeId.